# HERE SDK Prem - how to get compressedRoute?

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to get hotels to the length of the route, [using REST request](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-browse-by-corridor.html)

The request has a [parameter compressedRoute](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/location-contexts.html#location-contexts__here-polyline-encoding), but the conversion algorithm in Java script language.

Is there such an algorithm in Java or Kotlin? Maybe such a request is in the SDK, but I do not see it?

points to take from route.routeElements.geometry.allPoints?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compress the route. The problem was in the error of the example on JS.

First you need to go through to limit the number of points in the route, I set 120. If you do more, 414 errors may occur

```
fun execute(route: Route, categoryName: String, radiusInMeters: Int): Single<List<ItemPlaceByCorridor>> {

    val allPointList = route.routeGeometry
    val pointList = ArrayList<GeoCoordinate>()

    for ((index, elem) in allPointList.withIndex()) {
        if (index % (allPointList.size / POINTS_IN_ROUTE) == 0 || (index == 0) || (index == allPointList.lastIndex)) {
            pointList.add(elem)
        }
    }

    var routeStr = hereEncodePolyline(pointList)
    routeStr += ";w=$radiusInMeters"

    return mHereMapsApi.getPlacesByCorridor(categoryName, routeStr)
            .map { response -> response.results.listItems }
}
```

Algorithm transferred from JS to Kotlin

```
private fun hereEncodePolyline(positions: List<GeoCoordinate>): String {
    var lastLat = 0.0
    var lastLon = 0.0
    var result = ""

    for (i in 1..positions.lastIndex) {
        val elem = positions[i]
        result += hereEncodeFloat(elem.latitude - lastLat)
        result += hereEncodeFloat(elem.longitude - lastLon)
        lastLat = elem.latitude
        lastLon = elem.longitude
    }
    return result
}

private fun hereEncodeFloat(value: Double): String {
    val chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_"
    var result = ""

    // convert to fixed point
    var fixedPoint = Math.round(value * 100000)

    // make room on the lowest bit
    fixedPoint = fixedPoint shl (1)

    // flip bits of negative numbers and ensure that the last bit is set
    // (should actually always be the case, but for readability it is ok to do it explicitly)

    if (fixedPoint < 0) {
        fixedPoint = (fixedPoint.inv()) or 0x01
    }

    // var-length encode the number in chunks of 5 bits starting with the least significant
    // to the most significant
    while (fixedPoint > 0x1F) {
        result += (chars[((fixedPoint and 0x1F) or 0x20).toInt()]).toString()
        fixedPoint = fixedPoint shr (5)
    }
    result += (chars[fixedPoint.toInt()])

    return result
}
```